# Updating an "external content type" field on an SPList using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a simple Document Library that links to an External Content Type (lookup) called "Events".
Here's my PS script that loops through the list:

```
$spListItems = $spList.GetItems($spQuery)
foreach ($item in $spListItems)
{
      $item["Title"] = "New Title" 
      $item["Events"] ="Event Name"
      $item.Update()      
}
```

So...the "Title" column updates fine, but I can't figure out what I need to do to update the "Events" column correctly since it's an ext content type. Oddly this doesn't even raise an error, but the column is blank in edit mode. Any ideas on how to deal with this? 
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>An external content type represents data from an external system. Not all external content types are writable (update, delete, create) - it depends on how they were defined. What does this CT represent? Have you verified how it is defined in the BCS (business connectivity services) layer?</s>

As an example, read about how to configure an external content type to represent a SQL table. It shows how the ability to "write back" to the external system is an explict step in the designing of external CTs.

**How to: Create an External Content Type Based on a SQL Server Table**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557243.aspx

**UDPATE**

Actually reading your question again, you're not actually trying to update the external data, you're just trying to modify the *chosen* value in the lookup. Well, that's a little different. Lookups consist of a actual value and a display string. The value you need to set is not the display string, but is instead a value of the form:

```
ID;#VALUE
```

where `ID` is the foreign key in the lookup list, typically a number and the `VALUE` is the display value, e.g. "Event Name" In your case then you'd want something like:

```
$item["Events"] = "45;#Event Name"
```

You should verify the format by reading the current value out first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After some soul searching, it looks like I just had to update the column ["Events2_ID"] which I found by looping through $splist.Fields. I then had to just update this field with the ["BDC Identity"] value from my External List. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario, I was able to set the visible BCS External Data column via  a simple Powershell $item["BCSCol"] = "NewValue", but did also have to set the hidden field to have the change visible.  Interestingly, the value doesn't have to be anything specific, as it seems SP will validate the text value set via $item["BCSCol"]  after the hidden value is changed.

Not sure if this approach is supported, but it does work.

Here's a link that helped
[enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/f8116cb3-d0d5-4932-af66-703d86996bfa)